# Random Walk Proof

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Assume an asymmetric random walk.

I am a little bit confused by one exercise. Does anyone know my mistake?
We have to proofe:
$\mathbb{P}(S_{2n+1}=2k+1|S_0=0)= \binom{2n+1}{n+k+1}p^{n+k+1}q^{n-k}$

My solution: x denote the number of ups and 2n+1-x denotes number of downs. Therefore $2n+1=2k+1$
We know: $2k+1=x-(2n+1-x)=2x-2n+1$,

We compute x by:
$2k+1=2x-2n+1$ via algebra $x=k+n$
Substitude  in "Down": $2n+1-(k+n)$ results in $n-k+1$
Therefore my solution would be $\mathbb{P}(S_{2n+1}=2k+1|S_0=0)= \binom{2n+1}{n+k}p^{n+k}q^{n-k+1}$

Does anyone know the mistake? Thanks for help.

Comment: Only mistake is a dropped negative in your equation $x-(2n+1-x)=2x-2n+1$; it should be $x-(2n+1-x)=2x-2n-1$.  I think that should make the rest of the problem work out.

Comment: I am sorry. You are right. Beginner mistake from me. Problem solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries!  Dropped negatives happen to literally everyone.